# How do I get rid of unnecessary mp3 tags in my music library?

Tags: libraries, mp3, music

I have a massive bunch of music. Some of the tracks have unnecessary MP3 flags. How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you consider unnecessary?

Comment: Thats subjective and not relevant in this case. You can choose yourself which frames should be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the pollution of your library, try:

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec /usr/bin/mid3v2 -l '{}' + | egrep -e "AENC|ASPI|COMM|COMR|ENCR|EQU2|ETCO|GEOB|GRID|LINK|MCDI|MLLT|OWNE|PRIV|PCNT|POPM|POSS|RBUF|RVA2|RVRB|SEEK|SIGN|SYLT|SYTC|TBPM|TCOM|TCOP|TDEN|TDLY|TDOR|TDRL|TDTG|TENC|TEXT|TFLT|TIPL|TIT3|TKEY|TLAN|TLEN|TMCL|TMED|TMOO|TOAL|TOFN|TOLY|TOPE|TOWN|TPE3|TPE4|TPOS|TPRO|TPUB|TRSN|TRSO|TSOA|TSOP|TSOT|TSRC|TSSE|TSST|TXXX|UFID|USER|USLT|WCOM|WCOP|WOAF|WOAR|WOAS|WORS|WPAY|WPUB|WXXX"
```

Generally you can use `mid3v2` to edit ID3v2 tags of an mp3 file.

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec /usr/bin/mid3v2 --delete-frames=AENC,ASPI,COMM,COMR,ENCR,EQU2,ETCO,GEOB,GRID,LINK,MCDI,MLLT,OWNE,PRIV,PCNT,POPM,POSS,RBUF,RVA2,RVRB,SEEK,SIGN,SYLT,SYTC,TBPM,TCOM,TCOP,TDEN,TDLY,TDOR,TDRL,TDTG,TENC,TEXT,TFLT,TIPL,TIT3,TKEY,TLAN,TLEN,TMCL,TMED,TMOO,TOAL,TOFN,TOLY,TOPE,TOWN,TPE3,TPE4,TPOS,TPRO,TPUB,TRSN,TRSO,TSOA,TSOP,TSOT,TSRC,TSSE,TSST,TXXX,UFID,USER,USLT,WCOM,WCOP,WOAF,WOAR,WOAS,WORS,WPAY,WPUB,WXXX '{}' +
```

This will, recursively from the current directory, find all *.mp3 files and delete almost all of their id3v2 frames. And it does it **extremely** fast. Almost all means all, but:

```
APIC  A picture for the track, usually the albumcover.
TIT1  Content group description (I guess could be deleted too)
TIT2  The song title
TPE1  The album artist
TPE2  The artists (includes featurings)
TRCK  Tracknumber
TALB  Albumtitle
TCON  Genre
TDRC  Year of release
```

Compare [id3v2.4 specification](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames)

mid3v2 will implicitely convert TYER, the old frame for release year, to TDRC before deleting it. Actually it converts every file on every operation to [id3v2.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2). See `man mid3v2`.

Test if it worked, again with:

```
find ./ -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec /usr/bin/mid3v2 -l '{}' + | egrep -e "AENC|ASPI|COMM|COMR|ENCR|EQU2|ETCO|GEOB|GRID|LINK|MCDI|MLLT|OWNE|PRIV|PCNT|POPM|POSS|RBUF|RVA2|RVRB|SEEK|SIGN|SYLT|SYTC|TBPM|TCOM|TCOP|TDEN|TDLY|TDOR|TDRL|TDTG|TENC|TEXT|TFLT|TIPL|TIT3|TKEY|TLAN|TLEN|TMCL|TMED|TMOO|TOAL|TOFN|TOLY|TOPE|TOWN|TPE3|TPE4|TPOS|TPRO|TPUB|TRSN|TRSO|TSOA|TSOP|TSOT|TSRC|TSSE|TSST|TXXX|UFID|USER|USLT|WCOM|WCOP|WOAF|WOAR|WOAS|WORS|WPAY|WPUB|WXXX"
```

Comment: What you fail to mention is that the id3v2.4 version is not supported by all devices/software (even though the specs were published in 2000) including all versions of Windows Media Player. One should test a few 'improved' files on all devices one uses before changing, especially since mid3v2 cannot be used to roll back this change.